# Why is CollabNet Subversion Edge so slow?

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

We've got an installation of Subversion Edge installed on windows server, but it is really very very slow to wake up an we can't work out why.  Occasionally I have to restart the service.  The admin area sometimes takes 15 minutes to load - once it's loaded, it's fine.

The actual SVN seems fine, it's generally just the admin screens

Just wondered if anyone had any ideas, or had experienced this

Comment: Please add a bit more information about what exactly is installed on what kind of server and maybe on the server itself. Without more information it is impossible to give you usable advise.

Comment: check some perf counters to see what's happening. maybe its got no spare memory and is swapping, maybe your network is duff, maybe something else is chewing up all the CPU. If its just the admin screens then it sounds like the webserver is mis-configured.

Comment: Same here, admin page loads are ~10 seconds each...

Comment: Since you mention an admin area, I've assumed your question is about Subversion Edge rather than regular Subversion and edited your question accordingly. If I was wrong, feel free to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean Subversion Edge ? 
Did you meet the minimum requirements for installation?

Subversion Edge is written in Java and requires a Java 6 runtime environment. As a Java server app, it should ideally have about **512 MB of RAM** available to it.

Ultimately, the Apache Subversion server is likely to be a bigger driver of the hardware requirements of the server. Subversion Edge does not interfere with the performance of your Apache Subversion server. Ideally, it makes it run a little more efficiently by configuring and managing it properly.

More info, visit the [Edge FAQ section](http://www.open.collab.net/nonav/go/csvne2_r2a/faq.html#3) and raise your issues in this [Discussion forum](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/discussion/do/listForums/projects.svnedge/discussion)